# Disabling mobile web browser notifications when native app is installed

Tags: mobile, push-notification, notifications, service-worker

I'm at the beginning of spec'ing out a project to implement browser notifications. From a high level it appears like it will be something similar to:

- Create a service worker which subscribes to a pubsub topic.
- Leverage the Notifications API and WindowClient to publish a browser notification when an event happens and the window is in a non-foreground state.

Seems, straightforward enough. However, I'm getting a bit hung up from a mobile perspective. Namely, it seems to be the typical pattern that if a mobile device has both the mobile website open and an application installed, the native notification should take precedence and the browser notification should be silenced.

However, I can't seem to figure out how a service worker would inspect for the presence of a mobile application. It is entirely possible that I'm approaching this problem from the wrong perspective though, and the typical recipe for this is handled differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brent, IIUC your question is a non-issue because topic-based subscription is simply not supported by either the [W3C Push API](https://www.w3.org/TR/push-api/#webapp) or the [IETF webpush protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8030). I'm afraid that this is by design :-(

Therefore your native app will not be delivered the same broadcast message as your browser UA.

If OTOH you were talking about save-to-homescreen WebApp and a web-page running in a tab then, I believe, your service worker can choose which member of the active client collection to foreground (if necessary) but there will only be one toast message (if at all given rules governing blind/invisible notifications)

Comment: It appears there is another option at least if you're happy with [GCM/FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive) This is **very** exciting!